# I don't understand the meaning of a phrase: "elections are all there is to democracy"

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of this phrase: "elections are all there is to democracy" in:

> Perhaps this explains why descriptions of democratic politics
>   often create an impression that elections are all there is to democracy

Comment: In the opinion of the writer, when you read descriptions of democracy, it seems that just having elections is enough to call it a democracy. "All there is to" means "the full story"

Answer (score 2):

When saying:

> X is **all there is to** Y.

we mean:

> X is the essence of Y.

or:

> X is the most significant part of Y.

When this saying is used, the importance of other parts of Y are diminished.

Often, though, when this expression is used, X is not one specific thing, but a set of things. For example:

> To make a good lasagne, you need a savory sauce, fresh cheese, and the right blend of meat, spices and vegetables. And that's all there is to it.

Here's an excerpt from a book that follows this same basic pattern:

> You would say that peace is peace, and that is all there is to it.

This is saying, essentially:

> Don't overcomplicate things; peace is peace – what else is there to know?

So, back to your example usage:

> Descriptions of democratic politics often create an impression that elections are all there is to democracy.

The phrase "elections are all there is to democracy" means that, if you have elections, you pretty much have democracy. However, the first part of the sentence makes it clear that this would be a fallacy – that, in reality there is **more** to democracy than elections. As for the wording, though, here are a couple of alternative ways that myth could have been stated:

> Elections are **all there is to** democracy.
>   In the end, democracy **is** really **all about** elections.
>   There's really **not much more to** democracy than elections.
>   Elections are **the essence of** democracy.

Comment: My use of the expression differs a bit from yours, JR.  To me, "all there is to" something means there is nothing more to it, period.  I suppose it might be because my mother was in the habit of saying things like "You can't go, and that's all there is to it." and that meant that I would get precisely nowhere by arguing.  :)

Comment: @Bob - This may be a stretch, but, in your example, X is "The reality that you can't go", and Y is "The current situation" (also known as the pronoun _it_). So, "You can't go, and that's the essence of the situation," is a lengthy way of saying, "You can't go, and that's all there is to it."

Answer (score 1):

all there is to democracy= everything that there is to democracy

Consider the following sentence and how we form a relative clause out of it:

John bought the book.

The book (that) John bought...

Likewise, consider:

There is everything/something, etc., to democracy.

Everything (that) there is to democracy...

Since 'all' equals 'everything', the above can be rephrased as:

All (that) there is to democracy...

Answer (score 0):

Elections are only one component of what we could consider a democracy.

Another element might be "rule of law".

A system that has elections may or may not be what we would class as a democracy, depending on the presence or absence of several other factors.

The author is making the point that a false impression can be created by superficial descriptions of democracy as simply involving voting.

Comment: I am glad you said 'might be '.'Democracy' is one of the most contested words in the language. Think of 'The Democratic People's Republic of Korea'. Whilst I would agree 'democracy' cannot be said to exist without the 'rule of law', the latter strictly has little to do with it. Both the UK and USA had the  'rule of law' (even under slavery)long before either could be considered 'democratic'. In Britain the date of 1832 (Great Reform Act) is important, but many would contest that it arrived before women got the vote. Representation of the People Act (1918), the same  year in the USA.